# Jenkins Job stuck when repacking with adobe repackage script (keychain)

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, jenkins, adobe

I'll try to do my best to explain myself (I'm kind new here...)
I built a **job on Jenkins server that installed on Mac os (14.5.0 Darwin)**, what I'm doing is to **build an "IPA" file with Xcode plugin** (a succeeded to work with the plugin after decades).

Everything working fine (**even the unlock keychanin option in the xcode plugin**) until I run the last phase (before the "export ipa" step) that contain **"Adobe repackge script" (provided by Adobe themselves that resigning the app with a new certificate.**

In the phase, the **job is stuck (I need to go physically to the Mac machine, login and insert the Username+Password to let the Jenkins continue the process)**, it's frustrating!!!

I'm really familiar with Mac so maybe I missed something. I can't figure out what is the problem, I already checked the checkbox on the relevant certificate that any programs have permission to use here.

This is the script:

```
**# !/bin/bash
if [ $# -lt 3 ]; then
echo "usage: $0 path/to/ReaderClientCert.sig path/to/archive/build.xcarchive signing-identity"
exit 1
fi

RMSDK_DIST_CERT_PATH="$1"
XCARCHIVE_PATH="$2"
SIGNING_IDENTITY="$3"

# Check that the supplied cert exists
if [ ! -f "$RMSDK_DIST_CERT_PATH" ]
then
    echo "Error: Certificate file does not exist at location " $RMSDK_DIST_CERT_PATH
    exit
fi

# Check if the supplied cert has the correct name
# if [ $(basename "$RMSDK_DIST_CERT_PATH") != "ReaderClientCert.sig" ]
#then
#   echo "Certificate file must be named ReaderClientCert.sig, making a copy at " $(dirname "$RMSDK_DIST_CERT_PATH")
#   cp "$RMSDK_DIST_CERT_PATH" "$(dirname "$RMSDK_DIST_CERT_PATH")/ReaderClientCert.sig"
#   RMSDK_DIST_CERT_PATH="$(dirname "$RMSDK_DIST_CERT_PATH")/ReaderClientCert.sig"
#fi

# Check if the supplied file is an xcarchive
if [ $(echo $XCARCHIVE_PATH | sed 's/.*\.//')   != "xcarchive" ]
then
    echo "Error: Can only repackage xcarchive files."
    exit
fi

# App name is the only file in the .xcarchive/Products/Applications directory
APP_NAME=$(ls "$XCARCHIVE_PATH"/Products/Applications/)

echo "RMSDK_DIST_CERT_PATH = " $RMSDK_DIST_CERT_PATH
echo "XCARCHIVE_PATH = " $XCARCHIVE_PATH
echo "SIGNING_IDENTITY = " $SIGNING_IDENTITY
echo "APP_NAME = " $APP_NAME

# Copy certificate file to RMSDKResources in archive
echo "Copying distribution certificate to archive..."
cp "$RMSDK_DIST_CERT_PATH" "$XCARCHIVE_PATH/Products/Applications/$APP_NAME/RMSDKResources/ReaderClientCert.sig"

# Re-sign app
echo "Re-signing app with signing identity " $SIGNING_IDENTITY
codesign -f -s "$SIGNING_IDENTITY" --entitlements "$XCARCHIVE_PATH/Products/Applications/$APP_NAME/archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" "$XCARCHIVE_PATH/Products/Applications/$APP_NAME"

# Clean up extra copy of app binary generated by extract script
BINARY_NAME=$(basename ${APP_NAME} .app)
DESKTOP_LOCATION=${HOME}/Desktop
BINARY_COPY_LOCATION="${RMSDK_BINARY_LOCATION:-$DESKTOP_LOCATION}"/${BINARY_NAME}

if [ -f "$BINARY_COPY_LOCATION" ]
then
    rm "$BINARY_COPY_LOCATION"
fi
```

**By the way, the script working properly** I don't think that it's relevated to my problem (just add to show you what is going on).

I'm exsucted, please help me to figure out.
Appreciate any help!